# Database_Mysqli_result not found kohana framework, but it's there

Tags: php, mysqli, kohana

I've been trying to add a mysqli function
https://github.com/allanlaal/kohana-3.2-mysqli/blob/master/classes/database/mysqli/result.php

also using php 7.  This function is there and if I right click in the code, it finds the reference, however getting following error. tried changing the permissions to 755 and all variations of upper case lower case?? any suggestions?

```
Error [ 0 ]: Class 'Database_Mysqli_result' not found
MODPATH/database/classes/database/mysqli.php [ 192 ]
       $this->last_query = $sql;

     if ($type === Database::SELECT)
     {
         // Return an iterator of results
    return new Database_Mysqli_result($result, $sql, $as_object,   $params);
     }
     elseif ($type === Database::INSERT)
     {
```

Comment: I think normal MySQL was deprecated with PHP 7. I recommend you to use the last Kohana version compatible with PHP 7: https://github.com/koseven/koseven/

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Kohana autoloader is very case sensitive. Read [this](https://v2docs.kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/conventions#class-names-and-file-location) and [this](https://v2docs.kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/autoloading)

I'm guess that is on *nix? In Kohana calsses are case sensitive, and you should use `Database_Mysqli_Result` instead `Database_Mysqli_result`.

and filenames case should be:
`MODPATH/database/classes/Database/Mysqli.php`

and class name should be: `Database_Mysqli` not `Database_MySQLi`